# Microsoft Teams App - showLoadingIndicator : true resulting in breaking config tab

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-teams-js

I am trying to use showLoadingIndicator : true in my manifest file and as soon as I load the MicrosoftTeams.js file in my _host.cshtml file I call the javascript to notify success. But this breaks the config Tab. When I search for the item and select the result and click on save it throws error saying tabsettings can not be saved. But if I click on save second time , it works.:

_host.cshtml

```
 <script src="https://res.cdn.office.net/teams-js/2.5.0/js/MicrosoftTeams.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-0lOzlvRkoNWAcLkbUTuao6TaDa7zI7v+q2PUAm3lrMxUp43PFwf2kaQu7FYT9fjS"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="~/js/utils.js"></script>
```

utils.js:

```
 function AppLoaded() {
    microsoftTeams.app.initialize().then(() => {
        microsoftTeams.app.notifySuccess();
        console.log("app loaded");
    });
}

AppLoaded();
```

[image]

config.cshtml have:

````
 private async void SetSelectedResult(SearchModel selectedItem)
    {      
        
        _selectedItem = selectedItem;
        if (_selectedItem != null)
        {
            var settings = new TeamsInstanceSettings
                {
                    SuggestedDisplayName = _selectedItem.Description,
                    EntityId = _selectedItem.ID.ToString(),
                    ContentUrl = contenturl",
                    WebsiteUrl = websiteurl",
                    RemoveUrl = removeUrl"
                };

            await MicrosoftTeams.InitializeAsync();
            await MicrosoftTeams.RegisterOnSaveHandlerAsync(settings);
        }
    } ```
````

Answer (score 0):

You only need to call `microsoftTeams.app.notifySuccess();` in the -actual- tab, not in the config panel. Add a switch in your code somehow (based on page name, or a setting, or however you decide to do it) to only call that from in the main tab.

Update: You are also missing the call to `notifyAppLoaded`, which is even more important that `notifySuccess`. See in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@microsoft/teams-js/microsoftteams.appinitialization?view=msteams-client-js-latest),  that you actually need to call `notifyAppLoaded` to 'hide loading indicator'.

Comment: It is still the same issue. I updated the code like below:  ```  if (window.location.href.indexOf("/tabRemove/") < 0 && window.location.href.indexOf("/config") < 0) {
        microsoftTeams.app.initialize().then(() => {
            microsoftTeams.app.notifyAppLoaded();
            console.log("app loaded");
        });
    } ```` The app now also goes to unreachable saying - There was a problem reaching the app.

Comment: I think you -do- need `microsoftTeams.app.initialize()`, just not `microsoftTeams.app.notifyAppLoaded()`

Comment: yes that is already part of config page for setting up the settings. See the config file code in original post. Could you please try at your end, showloadingindicator. I think its a bug. I have a full working application, which works well without showloadingindicator.

Comment: @user25879 - We will try the manifest with showLoadingIndicator : true and let you know the result.

Comment: @user25879 -We are able to repro that issue, we have raised bug for the same and concerned team is looking into it. We will inform you once we get any update.